# Regexp to find images in html (golang)

Tags: regex, xml, string, go, escaping

I'm parsing an xml rss feed from a couple of different sources and I want to find the images in the html.

I did some research and I found a regex that I think might work

```
/<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\/>/g
```

but I have trouble using it in go. It gives me errors because I don't know how to make it search with that expression.

I tried using it as a string, it doesn't escape properly with single or with double quotes. I tried using it just like that, bare, and it gives me an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: To get an unescaped string use backticks. Example: \`mystring\`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a proper html parser is always better for parsing html, however a cheap / hackish regex can also work fine, here's an example:

```
var imgRE = regexp.MustCompile(`<img[^>]+\bsrc=["']([^"']+)["']`)
// if your img's are properly formed with doublequotes then use this, it's more efficient.
// var imgRE = regexp.MustCompile(`<img[^>]+\bsrc="([^"]+)"`)
func findImages(htm string) []string {
    imgs := imgRE.FindAllStringSubmatch(htm, -1)
    out := make([]string, len(imgs))
    for i := range out {
        out[i] = imgs[i][1]
    }
    return out
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/u06qpFJc2S)

Answer (score -3):

Ah so, sorry,Not worked with Go before but this seems work.
tryed at

```
https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1
```

.

```
package main

import (
     "fmt"
     "regexp"
)

func main() {
   var myString = `<img src='img1single.jpg'><img src="img2double.jpg">`
   var myRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`<img[^>]+\bsrc=["']([^"']+)["']`)
   var imgTags = myRegex.FindAllStringSubmatch(myString, -1)
   out := make([]string, len(imgTags))
  for i := range out {
    fmt.Println(imgTags[i][1])
   }
 }
```

I suggest to use htmlagility to parse any dom/xml kind a.

Read document by;

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(sourceHtml);
```

Parse by Xpath definition RegX fine but group ext. issues makes job complex

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(XPath here)
```

or

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")  // this should give all img tags
```

like.

i suggest this becouse it seems rss serves some html content ;)
So get xml, 
parse with XMLDoc get html content that you need 
then get all images by this.
For open answer.

after comment just need regex i think ;
my pattern is

```
 <img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>
```

for input

```
<img src='img1single.jpg'>
<img src="img2double.jpg">
```

and result seems fine 
in .net you must get by foreach via

```
.Groups[1].Value
```

regards.

Comment: Thank you very much! I already parse my xml with a different package, but I suppose I can use this to find the imgs in the description tag of the xml (which is written in html)?

Comment: So, what is that package ?

    http://regexstorm.net/tester

my 

pattern is : 
<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>    


input is : 
<img src='img1single.jpg'>
<img src="img2double.jpg">

.Groups[1].Value gives the image addresses???

Comment: `data :=[]byte(string(contents))`
   `reader := bytes.NewReader(data)`
    `decoder := xml.NewDecoder(reader)`
    `decoder.CharsetReader = charset.NewReader`
    `err = decoder.Decode(&dat)`

I decode it like this

Comment: This answer is in the wrong language, the question is about Go not C#.

Comment: Ah so, sorry,Not worked with Go before but this seems work.
tryed at 
https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var myString = `<img src='img1single.jpg'><img src="img2double.jpg">`
    var myRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`<img[^>]+\bsrc=["']([^"']+)["']`)
 var imgTags = myRegex.FindAllStringSubmatch(myString, -1)
    out := make([]string, len(imgTags))
    for i := range out {
        fmt.Println(imgTags[i][1])
    }
}

Comment: Oh. seemed so? Sorry.
Thanks goes to @OneOfOne